# Is function pointer type in _Generic assoc-list not working as expected?

Tags: c, generics, macros, types, c11

I was experimenting with "hacking" the type-system, by not restricting the function pointer argument to accept a function with a specific type of arguments. However, I still wanted to make it type-safe, so I thought I will combine this "hack" with the possibilities of the `_Generic` keyword.

I have the following four functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* printf() */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* EXIT_SUCCESS */

static void
function_i(int *i)
{
    printf("%d\n", *i);
}


static void
function_f(float *f)
{
    printf("%.2ff\n", *f);
}


static void
caller(void(*func)(),
       void *arg)
{
    func(arg);
}


static void
except(void(*func)(),
       void *arg)
{
    printf("unsupported type\n");
}
```

The first and second will be passed to the third, and I want to make sure, if the type of the function and the argument passed to the third is not right, then the fourth function will be called. Therefore I created the following `_Generic` selector:

```
#define handler(func, arg) _Generic((func), \
    void(*)(int*): _Generic((arg),          \
        int*    : caller,                   \
        default : except),                  \
    void(*)(float*): _Generic((arg),        \
        float*  : caller,                   \
        default : except),                  \
    default: except)(func, arg)
```

And then I called them:

```
int main(void)
{
    int   i = 12;
    float f = 3.14f;

    void(*func_ptr_i)(int*)   = function_i;
    void(*func_ptr_f)(float*) = function_f;

    handler(function_i, &i);
    handler(function_f, &f);

    handler(func_ptr_i, &i);
    handler(func_ptr_f, &f);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output is very interesting:

```
unsupported type
unsupported type
12
3.14f
```

I expected this to work for the first two cases as well, without the need to create a specific function pointer variable for the passed functions. The question is: is this an implementation error in clang's `_Generic`, or this is the expected behavior? Is so, I'm very curious about why exactly? And how to make it work without creating extra function pointers?

Thanks in advance!

---

**SYS-INFO:**

```
compiler: Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
flags:    cc -std=c11 -Wall -v -g
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you are facing is that the choice expression of `_Generic` is not evaluated. If it would be, your function names would decay to function pointers and everything would work.

Adding a `&` to your choice expression should fix that.

Comment: ahh.. I thought I tried that -- but it looks like I didn't.. silly me, thank you very much for the answer -- and yes, it is working now ;) *(I still have to wait for 8 minutes to accept your answer though)*

Comment: Relevant quote from C11, 6.5.1.1 states *The controlling expression of a generic selection is not evaluated. If a generic selection
has a generic association with a type name that is compatible with the type of the controlling expression, then the result expression of the generic selection is the expression in that generic association. Otherwise, the result expression of the generic selection is the expression in the default generic association. None of the expressions from any other generic association of the generic selection is evaluated.*